# Unable to render a react component on click of a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I have two components: `MainContainer` and `Cart`. In `MainContainer`, I have a button & when clicked it calls a function `addToCart` with an `id` argument, which then has to render the `Cart` component. I am passing that argument as a prop and then extracting the prop value in the `Cart` component. Wwhen I click on the button, component is not getting rendered. There are no errors as well.

MainContainer.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import { data } from "./data";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function MainContainer() {
  function addToCart(id) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Cart id={id}></Cart>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className=" grid grid-cols-6">
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div
          key={item.id}
          className="  w-52 h-64 m-6 flex flex-col bg-gray-100 shadow-lg border-gray-200 border p-4 items-center justify-center rounded-lg relative"
        >
          <Link to="/cart">
            {" "}
            <i
              className="fa-solid fa-cart-plus absolute top-3 right-3 cursor-pointer text-lg"
              onClick={() => addToCart(item.id)}
            ></i>
          </Link>
          <img className=" w-32 h-32" src={item.image} alt="" />
          <div className=" bg-gray-300 w-full p-2 rounded-lg mt-2 text-center">
            <p className=" font-semibold text-lg"> {item.name}</p>
            <p>$ {item.price}</p>
            <p>{item.rating}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainContainer;
```

Cart.js

```
import React from "react";

function Cart(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hi {props.id} </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Cart;
```

Answer (score 1):

`addToCart` is a callback, it can't return JSX to be rendered. You can store the `id` in local component state and then conditionally render the `Cart` component when the `id` state is populated.

Example:

```
function MainContainer() {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(); // <-- initially undefined

  function addToCart(id) {
    setId(id); // <-- defined
  }

  return (
    <div className=" grid grid-cols-6">
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div
          key={item.id}
          className="...."
        >
          <Link to="/cart">
            <i
              className="...."
              onClick={() => addToCart(item.id)}
            />
          </Link>
          <img className=" w-32 h-32" src={item.image} alt="" />
          <div className="....">
            <p className=" font-semibold text-lg"> {item.name}</p>
            <p>$ {item.price}</p>
            <p>{item.rating}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}

      {id && (
        <div>
          <Cart id={id} /> {/* render Cart if id defined */}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit unable-to-render-a-react-component-on-click-of-a-button]

Comment: Thanks Drew, but I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: @GurudattPuranik Do you have an example of the `data` array that is being mapped?

Comment: import C1 from "../img/c1.png";
import C2 from "../img/c2.png";
import C3 from "../img/c3.png";
import C4 from "../img/c4.png";
import C6 from "../img/c6.png";
import C7 from "../img/c7.png";

export const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: C1,
    name: "Chicken",
    price: "5",
    rating: "⭐⭐⭐⭐",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: C2,
    name: "Dosa",
    price: "8",
    rating: "⭐⭐⭐",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    image: C3,
    name: "Grilled Fish",
    price: "15",
    rating: "⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐",
  

];

Comment: @GurudattPuranik The `Link` wrapping the `i` element needs to be clickable. I've added a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unable-to-render-a-react-component-on-click-of-a-button-upmz7p) demo to my answer.

Comment: Hey Drew, that link is clickable. I am able to console log the data. Just that It's not rendering.

Comment: @GurudattPuranik I've provided a working example with both the `Link` and the conditional `Cart` rendering working. What *exactly* isn't rendering for you? Would it be possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox of the actual code you are using that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Hey, Thanks...will try to create a codesandbox module & will react out to you.

Comment: Can we connect through Google meet? It would be very helpful. Thank You